# Stream FLV video in browser

Tags: javascript, html, video.js, flv, ip-camera

I've got an IP camera that produce a flv stream on a URL like:

```
http://192.168.0.6/flv?port=1234&app=bcs&stream=channel0_main.bcs
```

The URL works fine in VLC. I tried to stream the video in Chrome with [video.js](https://videojs.com/) according to this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18414015/how-to-play-flv-video-in-html-video-tags).

```
<head>
  <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.10.2/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
 controls preload="auto" width="640" height="480"
 data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>
<source src="http://192.168.0.6/flv?port=1234&app=bcs&stream=channel0_main.bcs" type="video/x-flv">
</video>

  <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.10.2/video.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

I created the HTML file locally on my desktop and I've got the following error in my browser:

```
VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED) No compatible source was found for this media.
```

I'm stuck here, I can't figure out why it not displaying the video.

Comment: The Url you provided is not working for me in VLC so im not able to try and find a solution for you. Could you provide a working url.

Comment: The URL is on my local network!

Comment: Yes if you could open port 80 or something or even host it somewhere so we could test and see the problem

Comment: I'm not up for opening a port for security reasons.

Comment: The question you linked to is pretty old. Specifically, it's pre-CORS, at least as far as browser implementations go. I wonder if serving the stream without SSL (as `http` rather than `https`) is the problem.

Comment: Since the camera is on my local network, I don't see how I can get the stream in HTTPS.  The second thing is that if I enter the stream URL in the browser, it download a flv files. so I guess that not the problem?

Comment: In FFmpeg, try outputting as Fragmented MP4 instead of FLV.

Comment: @VC.One that sounds interesting. Could you detail more your comment?